# JPA/Hibernate: batchsizes ignored when merge

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, desktop-application

I've got a desktop application where I load an entity with Hibernate for the user to edit the information. This entity has many associations annotated with `@BatchSize`, and they're loaded accordingly, so there are very few queries. After that, the session gets closed and the entity becomes detached.

When the user finishes making the changes and clicks on the "save" button, a `session.merge` is called to save the new values. Because some of the associations are set with `CascadeType.ALL`, prior to the SQL update sentence, all the associations are fetched again, but this time using a separate query for each one, instead of a single one like when the entity was loaded, ignoring things like the batch sizes.

- Is it possible to instruct Hibernate to apply the same loading strategies when "refreshing" the information for a merge?
- Is this the usual way to deal with this kind of situations in a desktop application? Load an entity, detach, present it to the user, make changes, and finally merge

Thanks a lot